# Is there standard nomenclature for Confidence Distributions?

Tags: r, t-distribution, non-central, confidence-interval

I am wondering if there are standard naming conventions in general for confidence distributions or for the particular cases of the non-centrality parameters of (non-central) $t$- and $F$-distributions. For the unitiated, let random variable  $X$ have CDF $F(x;\theta)$. The confidence distribution CDF for $\theta$ is just $G(\theta;x) = F(x;\theta)$. This is somehow 'dual' to the original CDF. For creating confidence intervals one typically uses the quantile function of the confidence distribution, here $G^{-1}(q;x)$. So, given data $x$, the interval $\left[G^{-1}(1-\alpha/2;x),G^{-1}(\alpha/2;x)\right]$ is a $1-\alpha$ CI for the unknown $\theta$.

Are there standard names for these things? 'dual-t'? 'dual-F'?

Also, are there guidelines in R for this kind of thing? For example, `dt, pt, qt, rt` are the density, distribution, quantile and generator for the (non-central) $t$-distribution. What should I call the same functions for the confidence distribution? `dcdt, pcdt, qcdt, rcdt`?

If anyone has more knowledge of the history of the $t$- and $F$-distributions, I would gladly name them for pioneering researchers. For example, perhaps the $t$-distribution CD should be name for Johnson and Welch?

(**edited** again for clarity, probably still lacking same. Just looking for the *names* for these things.)

Comment: I'm confused about several aspects of this question.  First, presumably your "$F(\theta;x)$" is an abuse of notation to mean $F(x;\theta)$ (for otherwise you have merely switched the names of the variables).  But why can you call $F(x;\theta)$ *qua* function of $\theta$ a "distribution" when it is usually not normalized (and sometimes not even integrable)?  Second, what is meant by $F^{-1}(\theta; x)$?  If you are fixing $x$ and viewing this solely as a function of $\theta$, it's certainly not a "quantile function"!  Third, what's the matter with the usual terminology, "likelihood"?

Comment: @whuber, sorry, it is still early here. Briefly, yes, the CDF of the CD on $\theta$ is $G(\theta;x) = F(x;\theta).$ I can see how this caused some confusion. By definition, if $x$ is drawn according to the parent distribution with true parameter $\theta$, then $G(\theta;x)$ is supposed to be uniform on $\[0,1\]$. 
I am by no means an expert on CDs, and would only be using the 'quantile' function for convenience.

Comment: I believe using mathematical concepts that represent a completely different idea, such as [dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space), is not very useful.

Comment: @Procrastinator thanks for the input; the term 'dual' is also used in _e.g._ optimization, without confusion over the 'completely different' idea of dual vector spaces. But maybe 'co-t' and 'co-F' would be better, though? I value both terseness and unambiguity here. thanks.

Comment: @shabbychef I think there are serious misconceptions here. For instance, what you call 'confidence distribution CDF for $\theta$', $G(\theta;x)$ as a function of $\theta$ is not even a CDF as pointed out by whuber. In the notation $F(\cdot;\cdot)$ the first entry represents the argument of the CDF and the second one represents the parameter, $x$ is not a parameter. In order to construct a confidence interval, you need a statistic, this will define what you call 'confidence distribution CDF for $\theta$', the distribution of the observations $F$ is just an element for constructing it.

Comment: Thanks for working on the question, shabby. I'm getting a glimmer of what you're after, but some of the notation still makes no sense.  $F^{-1}$, in particular, cannot have its usual mathematical meaning: if $F:(\theta;x)\to\mathbb{R}$, then $F^{-1}$ must be a relation with the real numbers as domain, so "$F^{-1}(\theta;x)$" is nonsensical.  When you write of a uniform distribution for $\theta$, it makes me suspect you are thinking of $\theta$ as a *percentage* $q$ and that perhaps $G(q,x)$ is intended to denote an upper $1-q$ confidence limit for $\theta$ given data $x$?

Comment: ach, yes I edited the post, but forgot to make it $G^{-1}$. So, yes $G^{-1}(q;x)$ is a $1-q$ upper confidence limit for $\theta$ given data $x$. This is all based on the 'modern definition' of CD: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_distribution#The_modern_definition, which may be a bit, uh, obscure or weird.

Comment: How do you calculate $G^{-1}(q;x)$ if $x$ is of dimension $2$ or more? In addition, the space of distributions is infinite dimensional, trying to name its elements is going to be a bit hard.

Comment: The Wikipedia reference helps a lot.  But your account looks incorrect where it asserts $G=F$.  In general this is not true.

Comment: @Procrastinator, please take a look at that Wikipedia article.